# Remmina does not share folders or disks

Tags: shared-folders, remmina

I have Ubuntu 12.04. I use Remmina to connect with remote Windows XP.
I have configured Remmina for sharing my user folder, but I cannot see the folder in my remote Windows desktop.

Any idea?

Comment: For your information.
rdesktop is able of sharing local folders.
rdesktop works better thatn remmina

Comment: Try to activate Sound option in remote desktop preferences, it works for me.

Comment: Activating sound to `Local` also works for Ubuntu 12.04, using stock Remmina from repositories.

Answer (score 15):

As with Bor's answer, upgrading to the Remmina 1.2 "next" version solved my issue with folder shares not showing up when RDP-ing from Ubuntu 15.10 to Windows Server 2012 R2.

As in the instructions at https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki, simply run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp libfreerdp-plugins-standard
```

or in one line by concatenating the commands together with `&&`.

Then start Remmina =)

```
remmina
```

Comment: This fix works and is still necessary as of Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark), which only ships with Remmina 1.1.2 with a broken shared folder implementation.

Answer (score 9):

the following works from debian wheezy to a remote windows 8 pc using remmina 0.9.99.1:

first run remmina from the command line and see if connecting to your remote host gives any certificate errors:

```
$ remmina

connected to 192.168.0.x:3389
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The hostname used for this connection (192.168.0.x) 
does not match the name given in the certificate:
remote-pc-name
A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
```

if you see this warning then use whatever value you see reported instead of `remote-pc-name` in the `server` textbox in remmina.

then edit your /etc/hosts so that remmina can find the ip address of this server. make sure a line like so exists:

```
remote-pc-name 192.168.0.x
```

second, edit your remote desktop preferences in remmina like so:

**basic**

- share folder - set to something like /tmp

**advanced tab**

- sound: local
- security: rdp

make sure to click `save`.

after this, navigate to `my computer` on the remote windows desktop and click `refresh`. the shared folder should appear under `other devices and drives` right next to local disk `C:`

Comment: Dear mullhausen. I tried your solution. It does not work in my case. I have UBuNTU 14.04

Answer (score 4):

after upgrading Remmina from PPA (to 1.2 version):
https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki
folder sharing works with windows 2012 systems.

Answer (score 2):

rdesktop is indeed good at sharing folders. But rdesktop can NOT connect to windows 2012 systems.

Remiina does not seem to be able to share folders successfully with windows 2012 systems.