# How to share a folder with Remmina?

Tags: remmina

I'm searching for a full description how to share a folder with Remmina. While there are already questions regarding the location of the folder (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774752/where-is-the-shared-folder-in-remmina)) or why sharing a folder does not work (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288912/remmina-does-not-share-folders-or-disks)), I could not find any questions regarding the steps necessary to share a folder with Remmina.

Comment: It's simply a checkbox and folder selector  in the configuration of the RDP connection. Do select a folder to which your user has rw access.  Then from within your virtual machine (assumed to be Windows 10 in my example) to \\tsclient\Public. I think the name changes depending on your shared folder, but I did not test.
Most probably printer and file sharing needs to be active inside the VM.

Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/j4n2A2D

(Host: Debian 10 / VM: Windows 10 Enterprise -- It should be the same on Ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for adding this explanation! I wanted to add this question / answer here as a future reference for others, since it took me way too long to figure out how this works

Answer (score 7):

On the client:

- Make sure that Remmina is newer than 1.2, because of potential bugs related to sharing a folder (see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774752/where-is-the-shared-folder-in-remmina))

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
  ```
- Start Remmina
- Right click on the connection / click on edit, check "share folder" and select a folder on the client
- Click on save

Potentially restart the client / server

On the server:

- On Ubuntu the shared folder appears under `/home/<username>/thinclient_drives/` (tested with Ubuntu 18.04). Note: In my case the folder name consisted only of the first 8 eight letters of the shared folder (e.g "ClientSh" instead of "ClientShare")
- On Windows the folder appears under `\\tsclient\<SHARED_FOLDER_NAME>` (according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092838/363885))

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 20.04, Remmina version 1.4.27. The folder name you input in the `Share folder` field should be the absolute path to an **existing** folder on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Newer version of Remmina shows the SHARED_FOLDER_NAME as a full path, e.g. `\\tsclient\path_to_shared` (separated with underscores) as this [issue](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2561) and [commit](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/commit/1635bf2038eab55c883d743d9bd4838b39f6e6bf). If you don't want the full path, go to the **Advanced** options and in **Redirect directory** option put your custom mapping, e.g: `SharedName,/path/to/shared`. It also supports sharing multiple folders, separated by a semicolon.

Comment: I found dhqvinh's comment very helpful. I'd add: in Windows, go to the Network. Select the server named "tsclient". The shared directory \home\myName\sharedFolder is in \\tsclient\\_home_myName_sharedFolder

Comment: On Windows, open File Explorer --> click on "This PC" in the left-hand bar --> you'll see your drive under a "Redirected drives and folders" section at the bottom. If your shared folder path on your Linux client is `/home/myusername/SHARED_w_Remmina`, then on your Windows server to which you are connecting over RDP from your Remmina client, it will show up as `This PC\_home_myusername_SHARED_w_Remmina on myusername-`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [the main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290924/327339). Here's a screenshot of the window to edit a Remmina "Remote Connection Profile" on Ubuntu:

[image]

I set the shared folder to `/home/gabriel/SHARED_w_Remmina`. That's the path where it shows up on Ubuntu.

Once I connect to Windows through a Remmina RDP connection, I can open Windows Explorer to see the share. Click on "This PC" in Windows Explorer. I see the C drive under "Devices and drives", and I see the `_home_gabriel_SHARED_w_Remmina on gabriel-` driver under "Redirected drives and folders". Click it and it goes to this path: `This PC\_home_gabriel_SHARED_w_Remmina on gabriel-`. If I open up a terminal in this Window, it shows up as this: `\\tsclient\_home_gabriel_SHARED_w_Remmina`.

Note that this location is physically stored on the *Linux* computer, which is where Remmina is installed for me. If I disconnect the RDP connection through Remmina, the files remain on the *Linux* computer.

### See also:

1. [Where is the shared folder in Remmina?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092838/327339)